# Question about state and domain objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

Suppose I create a domain object called UserAdministration, if i have a method called CreateUser how would i pass state to this method, would I create properties on the UserAdministration object and have a CreateUser method or would i pass all the info for CreateUser method in a poco?

Also how do I identify my domain objects?

Answer (score 1):

> How would i pass state to this method

There are several ways, here are 3 of them:

1-Pass the values as parameters to public constuctor

2-Pass the values to a public method

3-Create public properties in the class, create an instance, then set each property and call the method without passing parameters

> How do I identify my domain objects?

A domain object represents a persistent data store in your solution. If you application is about CRM, then you are bound to deal with domain objects such as parties (customers, companies, etc.), ContactAddress, TouchPoint, etc. All such objects should appear in your UML Class Diagram. A detailed discussion of this could be found in UML, OOA and Domain Driven Design books.

Comment: @rchilambi,Did this answer help you?